# How to stop my telegram bot replying to a message multiple times

Tags: bots

My bot reply's to a message repeatedly how can I stop it? It is reading data from /getupdates. I need some sort of reply sent variable but do not know how to implement it

```
<?php

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "60";

$bottoken = "218567218:AAGQMx6lYCOhRapUXxIG5b0EkXTQOJ5y3uw";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$bottoken;


$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");

$updatearray = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$length = count($updatearray["result"]);
$chatid = $updatearray["result"][$length-1]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$text = $updatearray["result"][$length-1]["message"]["text"];

if($text == 'hi'){
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&text=hello");

} 
elseif($text == 'bye'){
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&text=piss off");
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use memcache in PHP or simply use a database.

Store the last `update_id` in memcache or your database.  That way you know what message has already been answered.  For the next time you can get the last `update_id`, increment it, and then get new message for response.

According to Telegram api document, You can pass last `update_id`+1 as `offset` param to `getUpdates`.

Comment: how can we get stop command to avoid to send broadcast messages to unsubscribed users?